# Is the Fourier inversion theorem valid for vector valued functions?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am currently reading Nakahara's book and he uses the equation
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int\mathrm{d}k\ e^{ikx}\int\mathrm{d}y\ e^{-iky}f(y)
\end{equation}
on page 507, which looks like the usual Fourier inversion theorem - but I think that $f$ is a function from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{C}^N\otimes V$, where $V$ is a finite-dim. vector space. I know that it is possible to define an integral for vector valued functions (e.g. the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)), but is the Fourier inversion theorem still valid?

Answer (score 1):

Here the vector space $\mathbb C^N\otimes V$  is finite-dimensional, so integration is easy; no need for "Bochner" or other sophisticated vector integrals.  Define $u=\int_A f(x)\;dx$ if and only if for all linear functionals $\alpha$ we have $\alpha(u)=\int_A \alpha(f(x))\;dx$.  Then this inversion formula follows from the inversion formula with one-dimensional range.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I can tell, your definition works in the more general setting, $f\colon A\to W$, where $W$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Is the following correct? - One can show that there is at most one $u\in W$ s.t. $\alpha(u)=\int_A(\alpha\circ f)(x)\;dx$ for all $\alpha\in W^*$ and in the case that $u$ exists, $\int_A f(x)\;dx:=u$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: One more question: What do you mean by "one-dimensional range" (or, more generally, range)?

Comment: In this case $f$ has one-dimensional range when $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb C$.  That is, I consider $\mathbb C$ to be a one-dimensional vector space over itself.  Instead of saying "one-dimensional range" maybe it would have been better to say "scalar-valued".

Comment: I understand, thank you! (I didn't know that range is sometimes used as another word for codomain.)